# I cannot import a class from another microserver using feignclient

Tags: spring-cloud-feign, openfeign, reactive-feign-client

I'm facing an issue while trying to create a microserver for training purposes. I have two components: Portfolio (the main one) and Layer1 (the component I'm trying to communicate with from Portfolio). When I implement a FeignClient in the Portfolio, it fails to import the Layer1 class. Strangely, I've seen examples that seem to follow the same approach I'm using, but for some reason, it's not working for me. Can anyone help me with this issue? Thanks in advance!

Here is the code for the FeignClient implementation:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oe7D.png)

I've compared my pom.xml with other examples that work, and it shoudn't be the problem.